What is the unit vectors at the origin of spherical coordinates
In cartesian systems, every point in space is assigned the same basis vectors, but in spherical coordinates, the basis vectors are a function of each point in space. So then what would be the basis vector at the origin since there is no privileged direction?

Are you confusing basis vectors with coordinate vectors? A vector space does not have a different basis for each point. A basis is s minimal spanning set of the whole space. Coordinate vectors are used to describe the location of points in space. In spherical coordinates, every vector is defined by a constant times $\hat\rho$.

@John Douma Aren't there vectors assigned to each point in euclidean space, for example in spherical coordinates the r hat vector points in the direction away from the origin, and such.

The origin has no well defined spherical coordinates. This makes the question about vectors there obsolete.

@JohnDouma The question actually aims at coordinates and coordinate frames on manifold(s). Usual spherical/polar coordinates in $\mathbb{R}^2$, $x=r\cos\phi, y=r\sin\phi$ have problem with the point $(0, 0)$.

@Korf Those vectors are not basis vectors. They are coordinate vectors. A manifold is not a vector space.

@ihan60220 Yes, but they are quantities that describe points in a space of points. A basis for a vector spans a space of vectors. There is a subtle difference. Think about a velocity vector drawn tangent to the trajectory of a particle in space. That vector is not a member of the space in which the particle moves.

May I ask where this question comes from and what you did to find an answer. Currently the question is of the form "This is my problem. Solve it." aka it does not meet the sites standards.

@Kevin Dietrich It's not really a problem I'm trying to solve, more just conceptual clarity, I don't know why asking this would be a problem. But I'm just curious if there would be any problem with assigning velocities, for example, to a system that goes through the origin if there is lack of basis vectors there

@ihan60220 There is no problem with assigning a velocity to a point traveling through the origin because the direction of that vector will be a property of the trajectory, not its location.

The short answer is that spherical coordinates are not well defined at the origin. There are no vectors at the origin in spherical coordinates and no vectors at origin means no problem with their direction.
The problem can be seen in $\mathbb{R}^2$ from the usual expressions for polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
x = r \cos \phi, \\
y = r \sin \phi.
\end{align}
We can see that there are troubles with uniquely assigning the value of $\phi$ for the point $(0, 0)_{x,y}$. (The defect also manifests when you compute the Jacobian of the coordinate map and check its rank at $(0, 0)_{x,y}$.)
From the practical point of view, roughly speaking, if you want to describe a system that goes through $(0, 0)_{x,y}$ then spherical coordinates are probably not a good choice. (There are possible remedies like using another set of coordinates that are well defined at $(0, 0)_{x,y}$. In some situations, the defect at origin is negligible since it has zero Lebesgue measure.)

Coordinate vectors, like those used in spherical coordinates are not basis vectors. In fact, neither $\hat\rho$, $\hat\theta$ nor $\hat\phi$ are elements of three dimensional space. They are vector quantities used to describe properties of points in three dimensional space, e.g. position or velocity.
In a vector space, the space is made up of vectors. A basis for that space is a set of vectors that span the space.
To answer your question, the origin has a position in spherical coordinates, i.e. $0\hat\rho$. All points in three space have coordinate vector $k\hat\rho$ for some $k\ge 0$ in spherical coordinates. Notice that the other two vectors are only used to describe velocities and accelerations.

How would one describe position or velocity with those vectors if they are not in three dimensional space?

@ihan60220 I can describe your weight with a number but that number is not a part of you. If I see a plane moving at $200$ mph in an easterly direction, I can describe that with a vector. Where does that vector exist in the sky?

"Notice that the other two vectors are only used to describe velocities and accelerations." In what sense is this true? Or more specifically, what are your preferred definition of $\hat \rho, \hat \theta, \hat \phi$?

Thats good and all, but my question is then isn't there a problem if every point in space is assigned a unit vector except for the origin? For example, how would one describe velocity of a physical system that goes through the origin

@Korf What is the position vector of the point $(1,1,1)$ or any other point in sperical coordinates? Only $\hat\rho$ is used. Note the hat. This is different than the scalar $\rho$.

@ihan60220 The bottom line is that these vectors are not basis vectors. There is a difference between vectors used to describe physical properties and members of a vector space.

I am not familiar with the hat notation. Imho, it would be nice to include some kind of definition or introduction to your answer.

@korf Your criticisms made it sound like you knew what you were talking about. This is standard notation in kinematics. In kinematics, we describe the motion of particles moving in a physical or geometrical space. These quantities are described by vectors. Those vectors are not part of the physical space. The physical space is not a vector space so those vectors are not basis vectors.

I also hope I know what I am talking about. ;) The notation that is standard in kinematics is not standard in the parts of differential geometry and physics I am familiar with. Therefore I would appreciate some sort of introduction of the notation.

@Korf It doesn't matter. Physics is enough to understand what I am saying. Suppose you have a particle moving in space. We can describe its velocity with a vector tangent to the path on which it travels. That velocity vector is used to describe a physical property of the particle. It is not part of a vector space in this context. As far as the notation, do a search for kinematics or dynamics in spherical coordinates. Polar coordinates can also be used. The position vector is in terms of a unit vector that points from the origin to the point. It is not part of the space.
